# IDAPro Loading C++ header files into IDAPro For structures

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

Anyone know how to do this?

Using File>Load C header file fails 
over too much wrong code.

Comment: IDA only understands C, not C++. From the help file: *"IDA reads and parses the specified header file as a C compiler does. In other words, it mimics the front-end of a C compiler with some restrictions:  C++ header files are not supported."* Best you can do is create equivalent C headers and import those.

Answer (score 3):

There's too much compiler-dependent macros, that IDA doesn't understand, in C++ Standard Library. Since a lot of the primitive data types, such as `uint32_t` etc, are already recognized by IDA, you can instead copy and paste only the structure declarations that you need.

You **can** define all the compiler-dependent macros in the compiler settings screen, but it's a very tedious process.

Comment: Oh Thank you! very good response, but I noticed that if i take only the structure definition, in case a structure is using another structure as it's memeber's datatype I have to keep a correct order of the declaration , is there anyway to avoid arranging what comes first and just push all of them as is?

Comment: @atigertest There should come a point where you don't need to know about the member datatype of a nested structure in detail. At that point, you can just define them as `void *` or put an array of char with reasonable size, e.g. `char *dummy[50]`